# Ip4v Rainbow Table

Tags: md5

a friend challenged me to find out the ip from the new web server he uses.
Is there a rainbow table or something similar with all possible adresses or are 4 billion numbers to much for a normal consumer pc ?

Is there another way to find out the right ip ? 
Is there any possibility to find it out if i know the webhoster where he is hosting ?

For anyone wondering the md5 hash is "f39d1e9bce27c0f31f536a272e544a16"

Greetings Tim

Comment: If you have a url it's easy, if you just know the hoster, that will not help. But cracking the hash should be easy, you don't need a rainbow table. In case your computer is really slow, you might want to exclude [reserved ip ranges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses) as well as the [assigned class A blocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_assigned_/8_IPv4_address_blocks).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It won't be as fast as a GPU, but a simple brute force script like the following python code:

```
import hashlib
import time

def ipv4_md5_search(hash, range_start=0, range_end=256):
    for a in range(range_start, range_end):
        print a, time.ctime() # show progress every time new value of a is done.
        for b in range(256):
            for c in range(256):
                for d in range(256):
                    h = hashlib.md5('%s.%s.%s.%s' % (a,b,c,d)).hexdigest()
                    if h == hash:
                        print a,b,c,d
                        return True
    print "No match found"
ipv4_md5_search('f39d1e9bce27c0f31f536a272e544a16')
```

will find the answer in about an hour (worst case) and will be significantly quicker if you parallelize it.  E.g., on a hyperthreaded quad-core CPU, just launch 8 processes doing:

```
ipv4_md5_search('f39d1e9bce27c0f31f536a272e544a16',0,32)
ipv4_md5_search('f39d1e9bce27c0f31f536a272e544a16',32,64)
ipv4_md5_search('f39d1e9bce27c0f31f536a272e544a16',64,96)
ipv4_md5_search('f39d1e9bce27c0f31f536a272e544a16',96,128)
ipv4_md5_search('f39d1e9bce27c0f31f536a272e544a16',128,160)
ipv4_md5_search('f39d1e9bce27c0f31f536a272e544a16',160,192)
ipv4_md5_search('f39d1e9bce27c0f31f536a272e544a16',192,224)
ipv4_md5_search('f39d1e9bce27c0f31f536a272e544a16',224,256)
```

and it will speed it up by a factor of 8.  I won't post the whole thing, but will say an IPv4 address in [dotted decimal notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Address_representations) matches your MD5 hash and the correct match starts with `84.200` (in the format `x.x.x.x` - no newlines or spaces or anything else).  Took me about ~15 minutes to find including time to script up and launch the tasks.

Answer (score 1):

This should be easy to brute-force. [This tool](http://www.golubev.com/hashgpu.htm) promises 500 million hashes per second on an average consumer-grade GPU, so it should hash all 2^32 IPv4 addresses in under 10 seconds.

It might be easier, though. When you can reach the webserver, you can also do a simple `nslookup` in the console (UNIX or Windows) to see the IP address of a hostname. But note that you might just get the IP of a reverse proxy with this method when your friends webserver is behind one.

Comment: A little more than ten seconds, I'd say.  You may need to try more than the traditional dotted-quad form: the address could be in decimal form or binary form.

Comment: @Mark - In this case, it is in the common dotted decimal form of `192.168.0.1`.